# My Java bluetooth server on raspberry pi running debian wheezy needs bluecove native library - where can I find it?

Tags: java, bluetooth, debian, raspberry-pi, bluecove

I have a Java bluetooth server running on a Windows box which I want to port to the Raspberry pi. I have lots of experience with Java but little with Bluetooth or Linux.

The pi currently has Debian  Wheezy operating system and I've installed bluetooth and Java ok, and placed the bluecove-gpl and bluecove jars in the classpath.

When I try to run the server, however, Java complains

> Native library bluecove_arm not available.

I've tried renaming `libbluecove_arm.so` from the gpl jar without success, even when setting  `-Dbluecove.native.path` to point to it.

Does anyone know where to find the correct library, what it should be called, and where it should be placed?

[SOLVED}

Found a sh build script on the google code site which showed how to compile the java source files, generate jni headers, compile and link the c files to produce a so library file. Only hiccup was that the library file needed then to be renamed libbluecove_arm.so before it would be found. All done on the pi!

Comment: i'm very insteresting in doing the same stuff. Can you give please your compiled bluecove jar for Raspberry Pi? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir bluecovelib

cd bluecovelib

wget http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.tar.gz

tar -zxvf bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.tar.gz

mkdir -p bluecove/target

cd bluecove/target

wget http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

cd ../../bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT
ant all
```

http://privateblog.by/raspberry-pi-kak-rabotat-s-bluetooth-na-java/